# Dispose of entity objects created by DbContext

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We are implementing DAL with EF Core and Postgres Npgsql provider.

Some tables have `jsonb` columns and we map them to `JsonDocument` properties in entity objects.

The page [JSON Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html?tabs=data-annotations%2Cpoco#jsondocument-dom-mapping) in Npgsql documentation has the following note:

> Note also that JsonDocument is disposable, so the entity type is made
> disposable as well; not dispose the JsonDocument will result in the
> memory not being returned to the pool, which will increase GC impact
> across various parts of the framework.

According to the doc, we have made the entities disposable:

```cs
public class SomeEntity : IDisposable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public JsonDocument JsonData { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        JsonData?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The problem is that `Dispose` method for entity objects is never called while `DbContext` is disposed correctly. The only way we see is to manually enumerate `DbSet` when `DbContext` is disposed and invoke `Dispose` method for each entity:

```cs
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }

    private bool DisposedEntities { get; set; }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeEntities();

        base.Dispose();
    }

    public override ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        DisposeEntities();

        return base.DisposeAsync();
    }

    private void DisposeEntities()
    {
        if (DisposedEntities)
        {
            return;
        }

        DisposeEntities(SomeEntities);

        DisposedEntities = true;
    }

    private static void DisposeEntities<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> dbSet)
        where TEntity : IDisposable
    {
        foreach (var entity in dbSet)
        {
            entity.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to force EF Core to dispose entities when `DbContext` is disposed?

Is above approach with manual entities dispose OK or it has some flaws?

Comment: Your domain model/entities could live before and after the DbContext, so I do not think the is the right place.

Comment: We use these entities only in DAL layer. Repositories convert them to models, which are returned outside. So, the entities could be disposed together with DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not OK. Your implementation loads whole table during dispose, because when enumerating DbSet - it loads data from database.

Consider to change function signature and dispose entities from `Local` collection:

```cs
private static void DisposeEntities<T>(DbSet<T> dbSet) 
    where T : class, IDisposable
{
    foreach (var entity in dbSet.Local)
    {
        entity.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, nice catch :)

Answer (score 1):

While your approach will work, the intent isn't generally for the DbContext to "own" the entity instances it hands out (and therefore to dispose them when it itself is disposed). You use a DbContext to get out instances, but at that point they are yours - it's perfect reasonable for them to outlive the context through which they were created.

In other words, it really is up to your application code to call Dispose when done with an entity instance.

Note also that if Dispose isn't called, there's no leak or anything, and so no catastrophic problem; all it means is that GC pressure will be higher, possibly causing some performance degradation.